# C# Web Service Method with Optional Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I want to build a `WebMethod` with Optional Parameters.

I knew the way to set `MessageName` .

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "Default")]
public void SearchPerson(String finger_print_base64)
{

}

[WebMethod(MessageName = "AddThreshold")]
public void SearchPerson(String finger_print_base64,int threshold)
{

}
```

But I want to set two parameters with same type.

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "AddThreshold")]
public void SearchPerson(String finger_print_base64,int threshold)
{

}

[WebMethod(MessageName = "AddMinMatches")]
public void SearchPerson(String finger_print_base64,int mini_matches)
{

}
```

And the Visual Studio told me an error.

> "SearchPerson already hava an method with the same type of parameters
>   "

Comment: The error is clear right? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You have three methods with same signature. How do you expect the compiler detects they are different? Although the `MessageName` property is for  *method overloading* in *web services* but your code should compiles first.

Comment: You should focus on you method declaration and not the name of the webmethods. Very obvious error, you have a method with the same signature.

Comment: This project is a HTTP WEB API.I want to build an interface which users can post some information to the server.The finger_print_base64 is a integrant parameter, and threshold or mini_matches is selectable parameter. So I just want to konw how to achieve this interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have tow methods with same signature , at least change the data type of one parameter or add another parameter like (boolean one) !

> > changing the name of parameter is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

At first : Overload in web-methods is not supported , IIS can't handle it.

Now The compiler can't build tow or more methods with the same name and signature under the same class , Because of , how it can address the method in the "dll" file without confuse! ,,

> > if you want to call your methods use Interface or abstract class and override the method from it in new three classes and call them :)
> >
> > "MessageName" is just an Allies

No Overload Because of the method name became an (address, or Url , etc) so the application will route to is without caring for it's signature , programming feature or even it's Programming language.